# Stripping "\" at the end

Tags: python

I want to convert a path name that I read from the command window to just the file name. 
For example, convert C:\temp\documents\tempfile to tempfile

I was trying to do something like-

```
filename=tempfilename.lstrip('\') #this gave me an error

filename=tempfilename.lstrip('\\') #and this did nothing
```

What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks for the help !

Comment: I am not a python expert but perhaps the \ is an escape character. Try \\ instead. Also you may want to double check lstrip does what you think it does.

Comment: @Jonas: No that's invalid. All raw string does, is to not evaluate escape sequences. `r'\'` is an error (you escape the end quote), but `r'\\'` would be the string "\\".

Comment: @Blixt: You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 5):

In Python, as in most other languages, strings can contain backslash-escaped character sequences, so instead of `'\'`, you need to write `'\\'` (= represents one single backslash).

Second, there is no method called `listrip`. For stripping at the end, you obviously need to use `rstrip`, not `lstrip`.

For your specific case, you should use [`os.path.basename`](http://file:///C:/C++/doc/Programmiersprachen/python-2.6.2-docs-html/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename).

Answer (score 1):

`lstrip()` removes leading characters.  That is, it will turn `\\\\\a\b\c\` into `a\b\c\`.  This is not what you want.

Use `os.path.basename()`.

Answer (score 0):

replace the '\' with '\\' and it should work :)

or is you are certain you will always have a '\' to remove,

`filename = tempfilename[:-1]`

EDIT:
oops. really didnt read the q.
`tempfilename.split()[-1]`?

my fist answer answers the title and fits with the `strip` suggestions, but in the actual question, it 
says:

For example, convert C:\temp\documents\tempfile to tempfile

.....

Comment: @Everyone, I did try '\\' it didn't work. listrip was a typo, i meant lstrip.